# How can I store an NSDictionary in a String:String?

Tags: swift, nsdictionary, plist, swift5

I'm trying to load a plist (keys are unique words, values are their English-language definitions) into a dictionary.
I can do a one-off like this:

```
let definitionsFile = URL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "word_definitions", ofType:"plist")!)
let contents = NSDictionary(contentsOf: definitionsFile)
guard let value = contents!.object(forKey: lastGuess) as? String else {
      print("value from key fail")
      return
}
```

...but it has to load the file every time I use it. So I tried moving the code to the program loader and storing the data in the definitions dictionary (the capitalized message is the problem area):

```
let definitionsFile = URL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "word_definitions", ofType:"plist")!)
if let contents = NSDictionary(contentsOf: definitionsFile) as? [String : String] {
    print("loaded definitions dictionary")
    if case state.definitions = contents {
        print("added definitions to state")
    } else {
        print("FAILED TO ADD DEFINITIONS TO STATE")
    }
} else {
    print("failed to load definitions dictionary")
}
```

It's failing at the point where I assign it to state.definitions (which is a String:String dictionary). Is there something I'm missing? Do I need to change state.definitions to String:Any and rewrite every access?

UPDATE: Based on Tom Harrington's comment, I tried explicitly creating state.definitions as a NSDictionary (removing the as [String:String] bit) and it's still not storing the dictionary.

Comment: What is state.definitions? And what do you mean it's failing? Please include all the relevant info.

Comment: Why does the first one need to load the file every time? Why not load it once and keep it in memory as an `NSDictionary`?

Comment: Don’t use `NSDictionary(contentsOf:` in Swift, never. There is `PropertyListSerialization` or even `PropertyListDecoder`. And by the way there is `url(forResource:withExtension:)` in `Bundle`.

Comment: Honestly @vadian, I've been banging my head on this for over 24 hours. I've gone over dozens of pages, recompiled 50 times, I've got a splitting headache and I'm left with alphabet soup from Swift's history. I've never had so much trouble for what seems to be a simple thing, something I feel should b built-in, and is built in, but only for info.plist. I don't think I can try and make sense of another thing that has a dozen prerequisites when I can't even get a sloppy version to work so I can have a foundation to learn from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put your code in a Playground that both generates a plist file and then uses NSDictionary to parse it out.  Here is the full playground

```
import Foundation

let stringPairs = [
    "One" : "For the Money",
    "Two" : "For the Show",
    "Three" : "To Get Ready",
    "Four" : "To Go",
]

let tempDirURL = FileManager.default.url(for: .itemReplacementDirectory,
                                      in: .userDomainMask,
                                      appropriateFor: Bundle.main.bundleURL,
                                      create: true)
let demoFileURL = tempDirURL.appendingPathComponent("demo_plist.plist")
do {
    if let plistData = try? PropertyListSerialization.data(
        fromPropertyList: stringPairs,
        format: .xml,
        options: 0) {
        try plistData.write(to: demoFileURL)
    }
} catch {
    print("Serializing the data failed")
}

struct State {
    var definitions: [String: String]
}

var state = State(definitions: [:])

if let fileContent = NSDictionary(contentsOf: demoFileURL),
   let contents = fileContent as? [String : String] {
    print("loaded definitions dictionary")
    state.definitions = contents
} else {
    print("failed to load definitions dictionary")
}

debugPrint(state.definitions)
```

Note I just made up something for the `state` variable and its type.

It seems to work just fine and prints:

```
loaded definitions dictionary
["Four": "To Go", "Two": "For the Show", "One": "For the Money", "Three": "To Get Ready"]
```

One thing I changed was your `if case ...` statement.  I'm entirely sure what this construct means in this context.  The Swift Language Guide says an `if case` should be followed by a pattern and an initializer.  In my code "state.definitions" is not a pattern so the `if case` always returns false.  But it seems to me that this should be some kind of compiler error.

At any rate, by pulling the binding of `contents` into its own clause of the outer `if` I can be sure that by the time I get into the if that contents is not null.

Comment: I was able to use your code to get it working. The if case bit was pushed on me by the compiler. Thank you. Now I can compare the functional and non-functional and start to learn.